# Projecting a field in MongoDB based of the value of another field

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document in a MongoDB 4 collection:

```
{
   "_id": <ObjectID>,
   "active_version": "3",
   "versions": {
     "1": "The first very long document",
     "2": "The second very long document",
     "3": "The third very long document"
   }
}
```

There are many documents like this in the collection, and each document may have many versions.

When querying for this document, I would like to retrieve only the text of the active version, e.g. "The third very long document". How can I accomplish that?

Comment: it means `active_version = versions.3`? what should be the expected output in the json form?

Comment: Exactly, the exact JSON format is not important but I want it to return only the string in `versions.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) to transform `versions` into an array of k-v pairs and then use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get first matching version:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            current_version: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        version: {
                            $arrayElemAt: [
                                {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: { $objectToArray: "$versions" },
                                        as: "v",
                                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$v.k", "$active_version" ] } 
                                    }
                                }
                            ,0]
                        }
                    },
                    in: "$$version.v"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "_id" : ..., "current_version" : "The third very long document" }
```